# Can't find solution to render blocking css and js , leverage browser caching issue

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

i am getting issue with page speed. Can't find solution to render blocking css and js , leverage browser caching issue. Is there any function or snippet so that i can increase page speed overcoming these issues?

Answer (score 0):

As with all things WordPress, there are plugins that do what you want.

But to leverage browser caching, that simply requires some [code to be added to your .htaccess file](https://technumero.com/how-to-leverage-browser-caching-wordpress/) - that's easy enough to do without a plugin.

Render blocking is much harder. As soon as you start re-ordering plugins and their dependent JS and CSS files, you tend to run into significant issues. WPMUDev have a plugin called [Hummingbird](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/wp-hummingbird/) which purports to take care of all of these tasks for you, but I've never managed to get render blocking resolved. You need to include one file at a time, and invariably, you end up breaking the site! :)

Comment: I used wp fastest cache plugin. Desktop speed increased by 6% but there's no change for mobile speed. Is there anything that i can do, so that it would increase mobile speed as well?